# WebSocketHandler doesn't call initialize

Tags: websocket, tornado

What I'm trying to do, is have an object (it's a gstreamer process that runs in a seperate thread) to be able to call the write_message() function of a WebSocketHandler

Here is a piece of code that I currently have

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', RadioSocketHandler),
])


class RadioSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        self.player = MusicPlayer(self)
        thread.start_new(self.player.start(), ())

class MusicPlayer(object):
    websocket_handler = None

    def __init__(self, sockethandler):
        self.websocket_handler = sockethandler
        self.websocket_handler.write_message("success")
```

However, it does not work. 'initialize' is never called. What am I doing wrong?

```
__init__()
```

doesn't work either.
Or is there another way to call a function from the RadioSocketHandler outside of it's own class?
I'm quite new to Python fyi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright I got it working with the following:

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', RadioSocketHandler, {'player': player}),
])

class RadioSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.musicplayer = kwargs.pop('player')
        self.musicplayer.set_sockethandler(self)
        super(RadioSocketHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MusicPlayer(object):
    websocket_handler = None

    def set_sockethandler(self, handler):
        self.websocket_handler = handler
```

I had to give the arguments to the **init** function on a different way. And I forgot super()